# Executing an EXE in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to execute a exe file in vb.net but i'm not getting any luck doing it.

I've found multiple examples on the internet doing it but it is not working for me.

```
    Dim file As String = "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\TEST\TestConsoleApp.exe"

    Dim str As SecureString = ConvertToSecureString("PASSWORD")

    Dim info As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(file, new_num)
    info.UserName = "USERNAME"
    info.Password = str
    info.UseShellExecute = False
    info.CreateNoWindow = True

    Dim p As Process = Process.Start(info)

Function ConvertToSecureString(ByVal str As String)
    Dim password As New SecureString
    For Each c As Char In str.ToCharArray
        password.AppendChar(c)
    Next
    Return password
End Function
```

When i run the exe manually or locally through vs 2010, it works fine for me, but when I put on on the server a response at all. What I mean by response is when the exe is complete I write to a text file that exe has been completed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try debugging the page that calls the code?

Comment: It sounds like a permissions issue. Verify that the directory has permission to read/write for the IIS user.

Comment: Hi Mike, yes I did try debugging it, and it works fine locally but when I put on the web server it doesnt work. I was thinking it was a permission issue as well, but i'm using the same impersonate username and password on web applications and they work fine. I just dont understand how this console application is different?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(TestConsoleApp.exe)` instead of the hardcoded `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\TEST\TestConsoleApp.exe`? I am assuming `TEST` is the name of your virtual directory, right?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I get an error on the server: the exception unknown software exception (0xc06d007e). Do you have any idea what that means?

Comment: That sounds like an error with the `TestConsoleApp.exe` itself and not the invocation of the program, so I think you are one step closer. Is the `TestConsoleApp.exe` your creation as well; in other words can you or do you have exception handling inside that console app?